# Show that infinite weighted sum being in a borel set is an element of the tail-$\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables, and let $\mathcal{J}$ be the corresponding tail-$\sigma$-algebra. Let $B \in \mathcal{B}$ and let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers. Show that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$, then $(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n-k+1}X_k \in B)$ is in $\mathcal{J}$.

I would need to show that $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}$

$$
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n-k+1}X_k \in B\right) = \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=j}^n a_{n-k+1}X_k \in B\right)
$$

since this would imply being in the tail-$\sigma$-algebra. I'm just not quite sure how to show this, the existence of the limit confuses me bit aswell, since we don't have any nice assumptions on $X_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed $j$ and fixed $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=j}^na_{n-k+1}X_k(\omega)=c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ we also have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_{n-k+1}X_k(\omega)=c$.

This because $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ and consequently $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}a_{n-k+1}X_k(\omega)=0$.

If conversely $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_{n-k+1}X_k(\omega)=c$ then on the same grounds we find that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=j}^na_{n-k+1}X_k(\omega)=c$.

This tells us that events like  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=j}^na_{n-k+1}X_k\in B$ are elements of $\sigma(X_j,X_{j+1},\dots)$.

This for every fixed $j$ so they are also elements of $\mathcal J:=\bigcap_{j=1}^{\infty}\sigma(X_j,X_{j+1},\dots)$ as was to be shown.